# C# Winform - OracleDataAdapter not persisting the records immediately

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am making changes in an old C# WinForm application.

In the code below, when the `DoWork()` function is invoked. It calls the two functions `PerformOperation1` and `PerformOperation2`. Both functions have a very similar body. The only difference is that they both update different fields of the same database table.

Finally, when they both have performed their job, we fetch the records using an `OracleDataAdapter`.

The count of the rows returned is 0 in the code. However, if I execute the query on the database straight away, it returns some rows. This means somehow the records updated by the `PerformOperation2` are not pushed to the database at the time when we call the `Fill` on the DataAapter.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    PerformOperation1();
    PerformOperation2();
    
    var sql = "select * from results where result_id = 1 and is_valid = 'Y'";
    var table =  new DataTable();
    var data = new OracleDataAdapter(new OracleCommand(sql, base.Connection));
    data.Fill(table);
    var count = data.Rows.Count; //It returns 0 But when execute the same query on database, it returns rows.
}

    public void PerformOperation1() 
    {
        string sql = "select seq_1, product, count_1, count_2 from results where result_id = 1";
        string updateSQL = "update results set count_1 = :count_1, count_2 = :count_2 WHERE seq_1 = :seq_1";

        var selectCmd = new OracleCommand(sql, base.Connection);
        selectCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(lCmd);

        adapter.UpdateCommand = new OracleCommand(updateSQL, base.Connection);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        AddCommandParameter(adapter.UpdateCommand, ":count_1", DbType.Double, 11, "count_1");
        AddCommandParameter(adapter.UpdateCommand, ":count_2", DbType.Double, 11, "count_2");

        var data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);
                        
        foreach (var row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            row["count_1"] = GetCount1(row["seq1"]); //Returns Count1
            row["count_2"] = GetCount2(row["seq1"]); //Returns Count2
            
            //Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        adapter.Update(data);
        data.AcceptChanges();
    }

    public void PerformOperation2() 
    {
        string sql = "select seq_1, product, is_valid from results where result_id = 1";
        string updateSQL = "update results set is_valid = :is_valid WHERE seq_1 = :seq_1";
        //Does exactly the samething like PerformOperation1 function above.
        //100% same code.
        //Only difference is that it updates different column named is_valid (with value 'Y' or 'N')
    }


    public void AddCommandParameter(DbCommand aoCommand, string asParamName, DbType aoDataType, int aiSize, string asColName)
    {
        if (aoCommand is OracleCommand)
        {
            OracleCommand loCommand = (OracleCommand)aoCommand;
            OracleType loOraDataType = ConvertToOracleType(aoDataType);
            loCommand.Parameters.Add(asParamName, loOraDataType, aiSize, asColName);
        }
    }
```

Any idea why this is happening, please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was not a coding issue. It was some underlying database view problem.